# How to execute a program at the powershell console from a ps1 script

Tags: python, powershell

I am new to python and powershell. To automate my testing as much as possible I am trying to trigger the nosetests executable to run at the console when I make a change to a specific .py file.

So far I have the code below in file filemonitor.ps1. When I run this at the console and make a change to file lexicon.py "Yippee" is echoed in the console. Good start. However, I have tried various commands to invoke the nosetests script in the action block. My research suggests that something like this should work -> Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { & $program }
However, nothing happens at the console. I think it could be something to do with the fact that nosetests needs to run from the project folder ie ex48 in this example. But I am not sure.

### Appreciate any guidance.

### filemonitor.ps1

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\envs\projects\ex48\ex48"
$watcher.Filter = "lexicon.py"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true
$program = "C:\envs\acme\Scripts\nosetests.exe"

$changed = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action {
    Write-Host "Yippee"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all in powershell for security no script run before you use

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy bypass
```

second 
for run programm u can use

```
Start-Process C:\Windows\System32\PING.EXE
```

or like

```
.\winrar.exe
```

third 
if you want run powershell script in `run.exe` or `batch file` 
you can use this syntax

```
powershell -noexit "& ""c:\test-webssl.ps1"""
```

ok and your script
System.IO.FileSystemWatcher just see your path and if you Created changed or deleted notify you see that

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
 $watcher.Path = "S:\soheil"
 $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
 $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true
 $changed = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action { Write-Host 

"Created: $($event.Args.Fullpath)"}
```

ok with another powershell if you make txt file with `add-content` or make directory with `mkdir` that powershell you run that notify something like that 
Created:
or in script you can end of script call `$changed`

Comment: Thanks. That worked great. I added the -NoNewWindow parameter to execute the process in the open console window. Just what I was after.

Comment: @TerryBrooks when you run that script see path and wait for change if change notify you but this is not what you want you  want script run every time and notify you it's better you create task scheduler put script on scheduler and when Changed happen notify you

Comment: `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` is a safer choice than `Bypass`. Also, I'd recommend using the call operator (`&`) rather than `Start-Process`.